# Apply a function to all combinations of two lists in R

Tags: r, list, purrr

I am trying to find a concise way to apply a function over combinations of lists - with the possible extension of do parallel computing. It seems to me that cross() function from the purrr package is not able to return lists as output.

I tried a nested lapply.

```
data1 <- list(a = xts(rep(2, 10), as.Date(1:10)), b = xts(rep(3, 10), as.Date(1:10)), c = xts(rep(4, 10), as.Date(1:10)))
data2 <- list(a = xts(rep(1.5, 10), as.Date(1:10)), b = xts(rep(2.5, 10), as.Date(1:10)), c = xts(rep(3.5, 10), as.Date(1:10)), d = xts(rep(4.5, 10), as.Date(1:10)))
data <- lapply(data1, function(x) lapply(data2, function(y) y+x))
data <- rlist::list.flatten(data)
sapply(data, first)
# similar to
# outer(c(2,3,4), c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5), '+')
# but returns new lists as output
```

The optimal case would be a fast parallel solution. My actual lists contain around 2000 elements each, and each xts in it is around 15 years long.